# How do you share game data between users?

Tags: ps3

I have LittleBigPlanet and Plants vs Zombies: Garden Warfare. I've completed LBP so now I'm playing Garden Warfare and it says I can't play. Long story short, I need to change the age restrictions I assigned to my PSN account to play (the game, which is 100% online). The only way to do that is to make a new PlayStation 3 user so that I could make a brand new PSN with a fibbed age. So I made a new user and a new PSN and PVZ:GW works like a boss.

My problem is that the LBP save data does not work on the the new PS3 user, since I've only completed it as the old user. I've heard for certain games (e.g Lego Batman 2) it is possible to copy data via the 'save data' area on PlayStation menu, although on my system LBT doesn't show up in there. However, I can't log into the old PSN with the game data on the new user nor can I do anything involving a PS+ membership, although if that's all I can do, I'll buy a two day membership. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried talking with whoever set those age restrictions in the first place? although ESRB doesn't rate online play, it gave the game an [E-10](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/Synopsis.aspx?Certificate=33272&Title=Plants+vs.+Zombies%u2122+Garden+Warfare) rating. so unless you are under 10, there's quite the misunderstanding going on.

Answer (score 2):

most saves are copy protected.. You could try to copy your savegame to a memory stick and then reload it on your other account, but it'll most likely fail.

Sorry (but good luck trying!)

Comment: Well thanks for that but I'd rather try a method that will 100% guarantee work still thanks for that

Comment: In fact I've just re-done the game data up to where I was so it's all okay. But still for others out there it would be helpful if we had some answers

Comment: Don't know why people downvote a correct answer =/

Comment: @Razieltje, I didnt vote, but most likely because there is no actual answer, no sources, and your suggestion is likely to fail according to you. So it really should have been a comment IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way: game data “save games” are locked to a PSN account on export (at least on PS4).—You are even forced to do a PSN login once, even if you use a local account only. And afterwards that local account can not change the PSN username (for logging in into another).